# Ansible filter - Need an explaination

Tags: ansible

I have a YML file to define variables like this.

E.g:

**/opt/ansible/role/defaults/main.yml**

```yaml
APP_NAME: False
SERVICE: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME] | default('')}}"
APP_HOME: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME]['variables']['app_home'] | default('') }}"
```

Could someone tell me what is the results of `default` filter and the `hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME]`.

Thanks so much!

Comment: According the documentation "_[... if the variable ‘...’ is not defined, Ansible uses the default value ..., rather than raising an `undefined variable` error and failing...](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values)_", in your case an empty string. Is that not the information you are looking for?

Comment: Defined and empty.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, it's so helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values) filter in this particular case as the other already commented is as follows:

```
SERVICE: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname][APP_NAME] | default('')}}"
```

Takes the special variable `hostvars` to obtain the `inventory hostname` in which will be working and apply the filter `default('')` which means that it is be defined and empty.

it should be equivalent to bash if iirc:

`SERVICE=${$(hostname -s):-}`

It's a way to set the default value to empty but ensure that the variable exists and it's "defined".

Comment: By the way, could you please helo me to explain this code?

Comment: block:
  - name: Replace text on file
    replace:
      path: "{{APP_HOME}}/{{ALIAS_NAME}}/{{regex.path}}"    #
      regexp: "{{regex.regex}}"       #
      replace: "{{regex.replace}}"       #
    with_items: "{{APP_REPLACE}}" 
    loop_control:
      loop_var: regex

Comment: I'm not sure about the policies but I'm quite sure that if you open a new question will be better for the community. But overlooking the code looks like it's using ansible [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/replace_module.html) for replacing text in a file with regexp.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will make a new question about this code.